# hide textarea in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#postcomment').hide();
    $('#createtopic').click(function() {
        var text = $('#editor1').val();

        $.ajax({    
            type: "post",   
            url: "Handler/Topic.ashx",

            data: "text=" + text,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#result").html(msg).fadeIn("fast");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    $('#postcomment').show();
});​
```

**html**

```
 <textarea id="postcomment" cols="50" rows="3" style="padding:5px;" 
  name="postcomment" >   </textarea>
```

I am unable to hide the `textarea`. Is it a wrong approah to hide a `textarea`?

Comment: It's valid. It's must be something else.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, is it not hiding for you?

Comment: Is there some other code to show it which may be getting executed at the wrong time?

Comment: Maybe he runs the jquery before the div in the page.

Comment: @prerna here is a demo of your code, make sure to have jQuery included, http://jsfiddle.net/EcJpf/

Comment: @prerna Check as suggested by gdoron

Comment: Actually when i comment the click function it works ,why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's working fine for me, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VWn3R/)

Things to check:

- Make sure you included `jQuery` scripts.
- Check if you have errors in the console.
- Maybe that `textarea` wasn't  rendered when the DOM ready
- There is some other code\css that override that `hide()` action?

---

**Update:** (After the full code added)

The last option is the winner... You override the `hide` with `show` in the last line:

```
$('#postcomment').show();
```

Remove it please...

Answer (score 0):

```
     $("#postcomment").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Comment: There is no point in using this, when there is a separate method to do this. Also I guess `display: none;` would be required. (I did not downvote).

Comment: O.k. I removed the downvote. But it still doesn't have any point as @Smamatti wrote....

Comment: @gdoron bravo for not "downvoting and running". You set a good example for the community!